# Null object in an array or list in protobuf-net v3

Tags: protobuf-net

In protobuf-net v2.46, I could serialize and deserialize null list entries by adding the following code.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(SerializableInnerList<MySerializableInnerObject>)][1].SupportNull = true;
```

But in the lastest version of Protobuf-net (currently v3.0.29), I see the error: `'ValueMember.SupportNull.set' is obsolete: 'Nullable list elements are not currently implemented'`

Does this mean if I want nullable list items I have to stay with the older version of protobuf-net or is there a new way of achieving this in v3 of protobuf-net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now: this simply isn't implemented. But unlike "dynamic typing" (which I actively want to kill), this one is probably one I can take another look at - more about timing and needing to ship than it being unsupportable. Let me add it to my list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc! If you added this feature to v3.x, would you be able to make it backwards compatible with deserializing objects serialized using version 2.x?

Comment: @tjsmith that would be an absolute inviolable requirement, yes